# Why does floating point addition took longer than multiplication

Tags: optimization, floating-point, addition

I was working with PIC18f4550 and the program is critical to speed. when I multiply two floating variables it tooks the PIC about 140 cycles to perform the multiplication. I am measuring it with PIC18f4550 timer1.

```
variable_1 = variable_2 * variable_3; // took 140 cycles to implement
```

On the the other hand when I add the same two variables the PIC tooks 280 cycles to perfom the addition.

```
variable_1 = variable_2 + variable_3; // took 280 cycles to implement
```

I have seen that the number of cycles vary if the variables changed depend on their exponents. 
What is the reason of those more cycles? though I was thinking the addition is more simple than multiplication.
Is there any solution?

Comment: Multiplication  can be easier to do than addition since shifting the bits over allows for instant doubling, So  50 x 4 can be done very quickly since you just shift all the bits over 2. 50 x 10 would be (50 shifted over 3 times(ie 50 * 8) + (50 shifted over once (50 * 2)

Comment: Your data suggests that floating-point operations on this platform are emulated. I have worked on multiple floating-point emulations before on multiple hardware platforms (including x86 and ARM) and in my experience, if the processor offers a fast integer multiply instruction, the floating-point multiplication can be faster than the addition. The addition requires one to distinguish multiple cases: Is it an effective addition or subtraction? Which operand is large in magnitude? Is the difference in exponents large or small ("near" and "far" case)? The multiplication is straight-line code.

Comment: I dug up some historical data on one of my floating-point emulation packages, and it suggests that with a fast integer multiply instruction present, an emulated floating-point multiply could be about 10% faster than an emulated floating-point addition. [A paper on floating-point emulation on ARM](http://www.dec.usc.es/arith16/papers/paper-131.ps) shows multiplication throughput at 1.28x the addition throughput for *double precision*. The factor of 2x you observed seems excessive to me, possibly indicating that addition is not emulated as efficiently as it could be.

Comment: the factor of 2x is not constant, some addition took 850 cycle to implement some of them less than 280- if two variables have the same exponent.
I can't do any thing with to addition to be more effective, in  assembly code it just call a routine that implement the addition.

Comment: Besides of pre-shift of mantissa for addition, also the intermediate result may require post-shifting. Multiplication of (1.xx * 1yy) may require right adjustment by 1 bit, but generic addition with negative addends may require multi-bit post-shifting as well (e.g. 1.111001 - 1.110001 = 0.001000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For floating point addition, the operands need to be adjusted so that they have the same exponent before the add, and that involves shifting one of the mantissas across byte boundaries, whereas a multiply is basically multiplying the mantissas and adding the exponents.

Since the PIC apparently has a small hardware multiplier, it may not be surprising that sometimes the multiply can be faster than doing a multi-byte shift (especially if the PIC only has single bit shift instructions).

Unless a processor has direct support for it, floating point is always slow, and you should certainly consider arranging your code to use fixed point if at all possible.  Getting rid of the floating point library would probably free up a lot of code space as well.

Comment: [The reference manual for the PIC18f4550](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39632e.pdf) shows presence of 8x8->16 bit single-cycle multiplier. Single-bit rotates needed to shift a multi-byte quantity are supported. From my experience with 8086, which also did not support multi-bit shifts, it is clear that shifts needed during mantissa alignment are relative expensive, but shifting should use byte-wise shift by register moves with only the remaining shift count (modulo 8) by 1-bit shifts/rotates. So while addition is expected to be slower, I would not expect it to be slower by 2x.

Comment: Clarification: 8086 did not have a barrel shifter thus no support for an *immediate* shift count other than 1. However multi-bit shifting was supported by instructions using a microcoded loop using the `CL` register, which however was *slower* than an equivalent sequence of `SHR/ROR/RCR reg,1` instructions.